# UiView on scrollView make memory warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this code to create couple of views and add them to a scroll view, on every view i have 4 images that i set in the loop.
when i finish i add the view to a scroll view and to and array that have all the views that i add to the scrollview:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows ; i++) {
    AlbumRow *tmp;
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlbumRow" 
                                                        owner:nil 
                                                      options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            tmp = (AlbumRow*) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    int y = 0;
    if (i != 0) {
        y = 85 * i;
    }
    [tmp setFrame:CGRectMake(1, y, 320, 85)];

    [tmp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    int imgInRow = kItemInRow;

    for (int j = 0; j < imgInRow; j++) {
        if ([album.albumItems count] > current) {
            UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:)];
            ItemEntity *entity = [album.albumItems objectAtIndex:current];
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    tmp.image1.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:entity.path];
                    [tmp.image1 setTag:current];
                    [tmp.image1 addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tmp.image2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:entity.path];
                    [tmp.image2 setTag:current];
                    [tmp.image2 addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tmp.image3.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:entity.path];
                    [tmp.image3 setTag:current];
                    [tmp.image3 addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tmp.image4.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:entity.path];
                    [tmp.image4 setTag:current];
                    [tmp.image4 addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tmp.image5.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:entity.path];
                    [tmp.image5 setTag:current];
                    [tmp.image5 addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            current++;
            [gestureRecognizer release];
            tmp.count++;
        }
    }

    [scroll addSubview:tmp];
    [rows addObject:tmp];
}
```

I need to add it to array because i use them in my class later.
This is how i clean the memory when i finish:

```
for (AlbumRow *row in rows) {
            [row removeFromSuperview];
        }

        [rows removeAllObjects];
```

I get a lot of memory warning on this code when i add a lot of items to the scroll view, any way i did something wrong?

Comment: Approx. how many views you add on your scroll view. Have you profiled it with instruments Allocations tool?

Comment: 40 views, and what is this instrument?

Comment: To measure your application's performance we use instruments. Allocations and VM tracker helps us in collecting and analyzing memory footprint data, it will show us where what is our application's memory allocation pattern.